# Android push notifications device token

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I've registered and enabled push notifications in my code, but on parse.com my device token is "undefined", so are badge and channels. Any suggestions as to why. Thanks.

Comment: Are you working on real device or emulator(Genymotion or Avd) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on emulator like Genymotion you can try this code for register parse.com

```
Parse.initialize(this, "YOUR API KEY", "YOUR APP KEY");
        PushService.subscribe(this, "CHANNELNAME", YOURCLASSNAME.class);
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, YOURCLASSNAME.class);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
```

I hope it will work.